How to define a Many-to-Many Model relationship with itself in Laravel?
I'm working on a mini chat system and my main model is User.
Each User has many Contacts. A Contact is just another User in the system. A User can send an add request to the Contact which upon approval, the two parties can communicate.
My Approach was creating a pivot table contacts which will hold two foreign keys of the contact users at both ends; user_id which is the one making the contact request, and contact_id the other user of the contact.
This is my implementation of the relationship inside of the User Model:
    public function contacts(): belongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'contacts', 'user_id', 'contact_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

The problem with this approach is that if UserA sends a contact request to UserB and approves it, then I try to get UserA contacts I get exactly what I expect, UserB .
UserA->contacts;    // Returns UserB

But if I do this:
UserB->contacts;    // Returns Nothing

UserB doesn't recognize UserA.
How do I solve this problem?
I understand it appears because belongsToMany always looks for contact_id but never user_id. I tried replicating every Contact row in my DB but the second copy has swapped user_id with contact_id and it works as expected, except that I think this approach violates the DRY principle and doesn't seem clean.

You've got what I like to call a "self-referencing bi-directional many-to-many relationship" here. You're correct that the core issue is that $userA->contacts and $userB->contacts both use user_id, which will only be populated for $userA, and your solution does indeed work, but is a lot of duplication. If you define the inverse: public function contactsRev() { return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'contacts', 'contact_id', 'user_id'); }, then public function allContacts() { return $this->contacts->merge($this->contactsRev); }, then finally $userA->allContacts

Sidenote, I have no idea how the performance is on this solution, or if there is another, better way to do this, but this is how I've personally "solved" this in the past.

@TimLewis this is actually better than my approach. Thanks for your help!

I think your original approach was fine. In many cases this distinction is needed, example in a social media platform: userA follows userB, but userB does not follow userA, and this distinction is important. In your case it is not, so linking both ways when one approves the request is fine, and would provide better performance for a bit of more storage due to duplication. The second solution while fine, optimizes for storage rather than performance. Knowing this, it is up to you to decide, depending on the application size, on the better approach.

I think you have two options:
If you don't require a BelongsToMany relationship you could do:

public function contactsInitiated(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'contacts', 'user_id', 'contact_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function contactsReceived(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'contacts', 'contact_id', 'user_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function contacts(): Collection {
        return $this->contactsInitiated->merge($this->contactsReceived);
    }

The other option would be to duplicate the pivot table record, but flip the ids so the relationship is bi-directional:
$userA->attachContact($userB);
$userB->attachContact($userA);

